# Docker: alternative to command line arguments

Tags: docker

I want to run a command like:

`docker run --network host ...`

But I can't actually change my docker run command. Is there another way to have Docker do essentially the same thing, like reading from a config file or environment variables?

For example, I know I can set a HOSTNAME env in my Dockerfile, which accomplishes the same thing as

`docker run --hostname my_hostname`

Is there a way to do this more generally with other arguments?

Thanks.

Comment: How about bash scripts?

Comment: Do you mean you need something like this? https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

Comment: Bash scripts: you mean inside the container? By then it's too late, docker's already running it. I can't wrap the call to docker run if that's what you mean. And I can't use docker compose either.